# jQuery click event like a toggle

Tags: jquery

Take a look at the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('#link').click(function()
                {
                    alert('1');
                },
                function()
                {
                    alert('2');
                });
            });
```

Alert 2 will never happen! However I'm wanting to make a link do something different on it's next click so like it's an off and on switch. How do I do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#link').toggle(function(){
    alert('1');
},function(){
    alert('2');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GaL9P/

Comment: @Cameron - There's another `.toggle()` function, just for this, it cycles through as many event handlers as you provide it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function()

$('#link').toggle(function() {
  alert('1');
}, function() {
  alert('2');
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`$().toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) does this.

pass as many functions as you like, and it will execute them in order.

```
$("#link").toggle(
        function() {
            alert("1")
        },
        function() {
            alert("2")
        }
    );
```

hope that helps! cheers.